# Calling this[NavigationMixin.Navigate] re-initializes the component

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components, navigation

I have a parent component that handles the navigation for my app and a child component that loads a list of data.  Whenever I call `this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]` it re-initializes the entire parent component and runs my `connectedCallback()` method again. I only expected the component to re-render, not completely re-initialize. This also causes all the children to re-initialize and the list of data to re-load and the scroll state and pagination state of the list to reset to the original state after the initial load.

The purpose of what I am trying to do is simply when the user clicks on an account name from the list of data, a popup comes up and gives some additional details.  I would like to be able to save the state of the page with the popup present through the navigation parameters to allow users to refresh or share links to that exact state, but I don't want the users to have the experience described above where the list is constantly re-loading and reseting.  I had this working in Aura before, but LWCs seem to be different.  Is what I am describing possible with LWCs?  Please help.

```
    @wire(CurrentPageReference)
    setCurrentPageReference(currentPageReference) {
        this.currentPageReference = currentPageReference;
        if (this.connected) {
            this.generateUrls();
        } else {
            this.generateUrlOnConnected = true;
        }
    }

    currentParams = {
        accId: undefined
    };

    get showAccountPage() {
        return this.currentPageReference && this.currentPageReference.state.liftiq__accId != null;
    }

    accPageUrl;
    backToListPageUrl;
    generateUrls() {
        this[NavigationMixin.GenerateUrl](this.backToListPageReference)
            .then(url => this.backToListPageUrl = url);
        this[NavigationMixin.GenerateUrl](this.accPageReference)
            .then(url => this.accPageUrl = url);
   }

    get backToListPageReference() {
        return this.getUpdatedPageReference({
            liftiq__accId: undefined
        });
    }

    get accPageReference() {
        return this.getUpdatedPageReference({
            liftiq__accId: this.currentParams.accId
        });
    }

    getUpdatedPageReference(stateChanges) {
        return Object.assign({}, this.currentPageReference, {
            state: Object.assign({}, this.currentPageReference.state, stateChanges)
        });
    }

    connectedCallback() {
        this.connected = true;
        if (this.generateUrlOnConnected) {
            this.generateUrls();
        }
    }

    navigate(newParams) {
        this.currentParams = newParams;

        if (!newParams.accId) {
            this[NavigationMixin.Navigate](this.backToListPageReference, true);
        } else {
            this[NavigationMixin.Navigate](this.accPageReference, true);

        }
    }

    openAccount(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        let newParams = {accId: e.detail.data.accId};
        this.navigate(newParams);
    }

    backToList(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        let newParams = {accId: undefined};
        this.navigate(newParams);
    }
```

```
<template>

    <div class="list-body">
        <c-list-container onaccountclick={openAccount}></c-list-container>
    </div>


    <template if:true={showAccountPage}>
        <div class="acc-body">
            <c-account onbacktolist={backToList}></c-account>
        </div>
    </template>

</template>
```

Comment: I appreciate this question. A sample code to show would be really good to understand and replicate your problem.

Comment: Edited to add code...

Comment: Seems to me that you probably want to use a modal overlay for the popup that doesn't use the navigation mixin at all. After all, the navigation mixin is there to allow you to "navigate" and present a whole new page, but what you want is to show some other data in a "popup". Take a look at [SLDS modals](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/modals/) and consider whether you can use a [lightning-record-form](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-record-form) in such a modal. Basically your current approach is entirely inappropriate in LWC.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I am mostly looking for an answer to my question of whether it can be done or not, not whether or not my approach is appropriate.  I am very well aware of modals and that is not the use case we need here.   The documentation clearly states that it is possible to navigate to same page with a modified state.  I would think there would be a way to do this without reloading everything.  https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.use_navigate_add_params_url

Comment: How about opening your browser's inspector/dev tools and take a look at network traffic - see if the navigate actually does a full page access. I haven't tried it but, given your description, I suspect you will find that the mixin does not implement SPI URL management behaviour but instead actually invokes a full URL and hence effectively re-loads the page with modified "state".